# issue with css full screen in different resolutions

Tags: html, css

I need your help. I have been googling around but i can not find good tips I am looking for. So I decide to write here. Pardon my English which is not my first language.

I am struggling to manage css layout with full screen with different resolution of browsers (big / small laptop screen). HTML Body works perfectly with full screen without scroll but wrapper (pink) seems out of control in different resolutions : the wrapper (pink) fits in a big screen (1920 x 1200), but it doesn't fit in a small screen (1280 x 800) that causes scroll. I dont want scroll. I need everything to fit in different resolutions without scroll.

You can look at my simple html and css codes with colour layout. You can just copy them and paste in your markup so that you can see what a problem is. Focus on the pink one.

```
CSS:

     <style type="text/css">
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html{
    /* This image will be displayed fullscreen */
    background:url('name.jpg') no-repeat fixed;

    /* Ensure the html element always takes up the full height of the browser window */
    min-height:100%;

    /* The Magic */
    background-size:cover;
}

body{
    text-align: center;  
    /* Workaround for some mobile browsers */
    min-height:100%;
}


section, footer, header{
    display: block;
}

footer{
    background-color: #111111;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    height: 45px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100000;
}
</style>


HTML MARKUP
    <body>
        <div class="header_container" style="background-color:orange; height: 150px;overflow: hidden;">


        </div> <!-- end of header_container container_12-->
        <div id="wrapper" style="background-color:pink; height:100%">

        <div class="featured_container1" style="height: 280px;width:100%;background-color:grey;">

        </div>


        <div class="featured_container2" style="background-color:red; width:300px; height:700px">


        </div>
</div>    <!-- wrapper End -->
        <footer style="background-color:green">

        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

Your help would be highly appreciated.Looking forward to seeing how to be solved by you. Hope it is worth to write on this forum :)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To stop the pink wrapper scrolling change `<div id="wrapper" style="background-color:pink; height:100%;">` to `<div id="wrapper" style="background-color:pink; height:auto;">`

I would also recommend not using inline css, and putting it all in your stylesheet too :).

Comment: it worked. thanks. but i see the pink wrapper height size is not the same in the small/big resolutions. I need both to be the same size fixed in different resolutions. Possible?

Comment: what size do you need the pink wrapper to stay at?

Comment: Not sure....i only need the wrapper with the exact same height size to automatically meet a side of the footer in different resolutions. The wrapper height size must not look big or small in different resolutions. It should be a fixed height size. Hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: If you're not sure of the exact height you want to set, then the best I can suggest is to set either a minimum or maximum height value. `min-height: 100px; max-height: 100px;`